# React-Native: Re-render App on state change (change in authentication state)

Tags: authentication, react-native, render

Currently, I'm checking if the user is authorized during app start and based on the result, I display the app. 
However, the user may sign in or sign out while using the app and I want to re-render the app in those cases so that my logic stays at one place (ie at app start).
Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, when an `state` changes, `render` function will call again. you can change `render` function based on an `state` and then when that `state` changed, the `view` has changes... for example:

```
render() {
    return (
         <View>
             {
                 this.state.authorized == true ?
                     <Text>authorized</Text>
                 :
                     <Text>unauthorized!</Text>
             }
         </View>
    )
}
```

so when `this.state.authorized` changes, `render` function shows different `view` based on `state`.

But if you want to restart the app on `state` change, you can use [React Native Restart](https://github.com/avishayil/react-native-restart) package and restart app when you want. There is no way to restart your app on every `state` change because there is many `state` changes in RN lifecycle and your app will restart frequently. I hope it will help you.

Comment: This would re-render the view and not the whole application. I wanted to re-render the whole app on the auth state change.

Comment: i just edited my answer, i hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
render() {
    const { authorised } = this.state;
    const userMessage = authorised ? "authorized" : "unauthorized";

    return (
         <View>
             <Text>{ userMessage }</Text>
         </View>
    )
}
```

You can also use props to maintain the user's status and render the components/messages based on the props values.